# Windows Server 2016 NIC Teaming on 2 switches

Tags: windows-server-2016

I try to configure Windows Server 2016 (Datacenter) for NIC teaming. All what i want, is to broadcast **one network** over 2 switches, which are connect **only** to server (no cables between switches). It doesn't work, network is broadcasted only on 1st switch, on the 2nd i dont have any access (tried with static IP configuration). I have 3 NICs (, 2 for LAN and 1 for WAN. Both switches are TL-SG1024DE, but i will try to get better if it necessary.

Thanks for answers, Andrzej K.

[image: Diagram]

Comment: It really isn't clear to me what you want.  Could you maybe create a diagram or something?

Comment: I added simple diagram of network.

Comment: That is an unusual setup.  Why are your switches not inter-connected?  Anyway, if you really wanted this setup, you almost certainly either need to configure the Windows box to either be a **bridge**, or maybe a router, but that will be more complicated.  I don't think teaming is what you need here.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

*NIC teaming* is not for anything like this; it's for doubling the capacity by distributing the load across two network adapters. Usually that also requires that both of the teamed ports are on the same switch as some teaming methods require the switch being aware of the team. And in such networks there's always cables between the switches. If your clients are supposed to be on the same subnet, that's the easiest solution - the one you should use!

Closest to the diagram would be called *routing* and it would require that you have two networks with separate and not overlapping subnets. It would be perfectly possible to use Windows Server 2016 as a router between these networks and the Internet, but if there's no need for firewall between the networks or something like that, the suggestion on the first paragraph is way superior in performance.

Comment: I want avoid setuping  2nd network. Some ports from 1st room and 2nd, are devided between both switches and I  want to have access to all client. In a few day i will create VLAN for every client (no LAN games) and then will be access from server or this network.

Answer (score 0):

As it appears, there's no connection between both subnets. However, the server's NICs both carry IP addresses valid on *both* subnets, so it'll get confused as to where to route the packets - it won't work. NIC teaming won't make it work magically but add to the confusion.

There are two (easy) ways to this:

1) two subnets: use different subnets for both NIC/switch sets. That way, clients can only connect to their dedicated NIC. If you need subnet-to-subnet communication, connect them with a router (your server can also be used as router).

2) single subnet: connect the switches and use different IP addresses for the server NICs. No, there's no way to ensure your clients are using the 'nearest' NIC if you use simple round-robin DNS.